# AWS Elastic Beanstalk healthd uses wrong timezone for nginx logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

With configuration from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-serverlogs.html the nxing generates log files named by local timezone but healthd looks for files with UTC (i guess) named logs:

```
[2023-12-12T14:12:05.600240 #4544]  WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2023-12-12-13" does not exist
```

Is there any way to force either nginx logs or healthd to match (or a place to fill bug report for healthd at least)?